# Bugsnag integration for TYPO3

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, bugsnag

I would like to integrate Bugsnag into TYPO3.

Is there a recommended way to do this? 
This is for a production system, so debug information is disabled, but it would be great to get these infos for bugsnag?

https://docs.bugsnag.com/platforms/php/other/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [customize exception and error handling in TYPO3](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/8.7/en-us/ApiOverview/ErrorAndExceptionHandling/Configuration/Extending/Index.html).

There is [a TYPO3 bugsnag extension](https://extensions.typo3.org/extension/bugsnag) you can use.